# Use 'this' keyword as a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would use the selector of my event to put in my function, but it doesn't work.

I already try some tricks I'll show in the following code.

```
// the actual code
$('#voyages').on('click', function() {
  if (continentOuvert == false) {
    $('#voyages i.fas.fa-arrow-up').show(500);
    $('#voyages i.fas.fa-arrow-down').hide();
  }
});

// the functions I try to make
function arrowUp() {
  $('this i.fas.fa-arrow-up').show(500);
  $('this i.fas.fa-arrow-down').hide();
}

// or
function arrowUp() {
  $(this + ' i.fas.fa-arrow-up').show(500);
  $(this + ' i.fas.fa-arrow-down').hide();
}
```

Nothing happens, I think I didn't do right.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should not use `this + string/class names` in your arrowUp function, as `this` is an object and doing so will not give you any reference but only a very vague string like `[object]strstrstr`

Comment: A tip, do `console.log( $(this).find('i.fas.fa-arrow-up') )` in your code and checl in browser console what element you get by that. this will help you to understand what the code is doing / selecting

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` method:

```
$(this).find('i.fas.fa-arrow-up').show(500);
$(this).find('i.fas.fa-arrow-down').hide();
```

Comment: Alternative syntax:  `$("i.fas.fa-arrow-up", this).show(500);`

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned `$(this)` cannot be a selector because it's an object not a string. As an alternative you can use `$(e.target)` which points to the clicked element (ie `.voyages`), always pass the Event Object (it's the `e` variable in the demo).  `.toggleClass()` will streamline your code. Also jQuery is flexible so do not use #id use .class as much as possible.

```js
$('.voyages').on('click', function(e) {
  var icon = $(e.target).find('.fas');
  icon.toggleClass('fa-flip-vertical');
});
```

```css
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 24px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class='voyages'>Voyages <i class='fas fa-arrow-up'></i></button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for all your reply. I finally use this code :

```js
function arrowUp(id) {
            $(id + ' i.fas.fa-arrow-up').show(500);
            $(id + ' i.fas.fa-arrow-down').hide();
        }
```

```js
arrowUp('#'+$(this).attr('id'));
```